# SAP Webservice Call - 413 Request Entity too Large

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I am having trouble trying to send XML request to a webservice Call via SAP. I have no problems at all when i extract the XML request from SAP Trace to SOAPUI.

Below is the trace i get from SMICM Transaction:
[image]

Here is the J2ee Engine version:
[image]

RZ10 icm parameter adjustment already but still didn't fix my issue.
[image]

Below is the XML Request (that i extracted from SAP) and when executed in SOAPUI it throws successful Response.
[image]

Comment: How do you do that call? ABAP-Proxy? Or you are calling SAP-exposed web-service from outside?

Comment: Yes abap-proxy and they have wsdl so i call their webservice.

Comment: So give the code, where you call it, and also give wsdl, obscuring private data.

Comment: i have included on my question the XML request i populated on the ABAP-Proxy call and i dont think there is something wrong with the code. Because when i run it via SOAPUI it is successful and only in SAP it throws me this error.